# What is the best method to signal the editing in the form above of an table to a user?

Tags: forms, tables, edit

To add an entry to the table, a user must fill out the form above and click the Take it button. He can also edit an existing entry by clicking on the pencil. How can you best signal to the user that this data record has then been loaded into the form above in order to be able to edit it?

Is this an understandable operating concept?
Are there any other disadvantages?

[image: Wireframe with Fomular above of a table]

[EDIT 1 from here]
Okay, my problem is a little bigger. I clarify my question. I am already in a modal window for editing the article data record and have to create several conditions again. And I don't really want to put a modal window on top of a modal window.

[image: Wireframe with Fomular above of a table in a modal window]

Comment: Is the pattern that the user selects an item BELOW in the list, then it populates ABOVE to edit? Also, is this constrained to a specific viewport (desktop, mobile)?

Comment: @MikeM: Yes. I want to use it for the desktop.

Comment: Is there also a way to ADD a new item to the list? What does the action TAKE IT do?

Comment: Yes, an new item can be added with the Button "Take it". This is a bad translation for the german word "Übernehmen". In english it would be better to use "Add". You're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Leverage common patterns whenever possible; users come to your application with lots of shared patterns from other sources.

##### The form above (current) approach: Is there a specific reason to use a vertical pattern?

Going from detail to list vertically tends to confuse which elements are grouped together. We often approach a list first for *what's already present*, then make decisions as to Add a new item to the collection, or edit / delete what's there already.

Since most desktop viewports are wider than tall, making a vertical add pattern tends to be confusing for several reasons:

- The value of the list is to show all elements already created, and to quickly search for a particular item or value. Putting the list **below the
  list** will push down some of the elements.
- The action buttons such a <kbd>Take It</kbd> and <kbd>Clear Fields</kbd> look like they belong to the table (which is a common pattern)
- There's also not an obvious way to abandon an edit. 'Clear fields' is different than Cancel. There needs to be an exit that reverts any edits to the pre-edit state. 'Cancel' is a common label for this.

##### A list detail pattern on desktop using a panel

Try honoring the list and provide a quick way to edit in place by using either a dialog or sliding panel. It's a common way to add or edit items in a collection.

[image]
The panel comes in from the side when editing or adding a new item:

[image]

Now if there's a sub object (the conditions), focus their attention by drilling into a condition detail:

[image]

Comment: Okay, my problem is a little bigger. I clarify my question again above.

Comment: are the conditions similar to a sub-object for the instance you're creating? It seems like you have to do a drilldown while editing to add/edit a condition, and save that

Comment: Conditions are price conditions that are negotiated with a supplier for each article. What do you mean with drilldown? There can be several conditions per article. For example, a discount from a certain purchase quantity.

Comment: @Jean I've updated my answer to allow for a drilldown pattern within the panel, so things don't feel like they're stacking on top of each other. This can scale, because you can pin the save buttons to the bottom, and allow vertical scroll in the case of long forms.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. I'll leave the question open for a few more days to see if anyone has another idea.

Comment: I have an additional question: How can I delete a condition in this pattern? Do I have to click on the minus icon (-) and then press save afterwards? It doesn't feel right and it's easy to forget to save.

Comment: Well, that depends on what the relationship of conditions are (something I don't have the insight into). If conditions are something with their own list and can be added to one or more inventory items, then you'd want to just remove them, and deleting is an action managed somewhere else. You could use a disabled SAVE button, where and edits other than removing the condition prompts a save. If forgetting to Save is an issue, why not question the save button for ANY edits?

Comment: The problem at this point is that constant automatic saving at this point is very difficult to implement because there is a lot of time-consuming logic in the backend. But it would certainly be the best option to always save everything and also have an undo function.
Thanks for the nice discussion. I'll definitely take suggestions.